# Detecting ads in audio streams?

Tags: audio, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I have never tried, but just curious if there is any possibility to detect ads in audio streams? I mean except machine learning or something. Some specifics about byte stream during adverts. Maybe kind of different loud value?

Answer (score 1):

From a purely audio standpoint, this isn't possible.  There is nothing distinguishable between an advertisement and other audio content.  Sure, you could argue that a station playing music will have different spectral characteristics than when talking comes on for an advertisement, but what about ads that also play music?  How do you distinguish between an announcer and someone reading an ad?  What if the ad is embedded in normal content?

Now, some stations do provide metadata which occasionally contain ad information.  If you look at the length of a particular content item, your ads are usually going to be under a minute or 30 seconds.  How you get this metadata and deal with it depend on the kind of stream you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques emerging to do this and they tend to leverage databases of known adverts to get around the theoretical problems that Brad correctly highlights in his answer.

One of the references below however, uses a techniques based on detecting slight differences in the audio when an ad starts as the initial detection trigger.

Some techniques also use both audio and visual streams to aid detection - for example the Google paper below uses first audio matching and then the video to validate/verify.

Some sources that might be worth looking at for anyone interested in this area (I realise it is an old question but it is still topical):

- http://www.xavieranguera.com/papers/cimca_2008.pdf
- http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/55.pdf
- https://www.audiblemagic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ad_detection_datasheet_150406.pdf